# VCard check if contact has name

Tags: android, contacts

I use the the library **CARDME** 3.6 in my application but the problem is that i didn't find any feature to tell if contact has name or not, because some contacts on phone are only phone number or email
i tried to use this

```
card.getName().hasGivenName()   or    card.getName().hasFamilyName()
```

but its return error so it is there any way to check the contact when it have no name thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check to see if `card.getName()` returns null or not.  If it returns null, it probably means the vCard property that contains the name was missing from the vCard.  So your check should be:

```
card.getName() != null and (card.getName().hasGivenName() or card.getName().hasFamilyName())
```